# ASP.NET Core 6 : why Get REST method does not work?

Tags: asp.net-core

I develop a new ASP.NET Core 6 service. In browser I go to `https://localhost:8804/api/deals/total`:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public int GetTotal()
 {
     return 174;
 }
```

This controller does not work - I get a 404 error.

But if add a parameter, it works:

```
 [HttpGet("{par}")]
 public int GetTotal(int? par)
 {
       return 174;
 }
```

Note: Swagger displays it and I can test, but the problem occurs in the browser.

Why does this method not work in the 1st case?

That is controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace P2AWS.Controllers;
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DealsController : ControllerBase
    {
        //[HttpGet] //<---- does not work
        //public int GetTotal()
        //{
        //    return 174;
        //}

        [HttpGet("{par}")]
        public int GetTotal(int? par)
        {
            return 174;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please show the **whole** controller - not just a single method. And have you done anything special / custom in the setup code for this API? Any special routings etc.?

Comment: Is it possible to attach project zip here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've used the default setup for ASP.NET Core MVC, you probably just need to ensure that the controller defines the "base" fragment of the request URL, and you need to add a "route" spec to the method:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]   // to get the "/api/deals" in your URL
public class DealsController : ControllerBase
{
     // ....

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("total")]       // to get the "/total" after /api/deals
    public int GetTotal()
    {
         return 174;
    }
}
```

In your controller code, you're missing the `[ApiController]` annotation on the controller class, and the `[Route("total")]` annotation on the method.

Try to add these - does it work now?

Comment: Thank you !!! It works, my stupid mistake     [Route("total")]          [HttpGet]
    public int GetTotal()
    {
        return 174;
    }

Comment: Btw, how it works without route but with parameter? (see the 1st msg)

Comment: @ZedZip: no idea ;-) if you don't have a "Route" annotation, then the method name is the name in the URL - so most likely, you use /api/deals/gettotal(0) or something like that. The "Route" annotation allows you to define a URL part that is different from the method name in your C# class

Comment: The code
   // [Route("total")] 
    [HttpGet]
    public int GetTotal()
    {
        return 174;
    }

    [HttpGet("{par}")] // it works
    public int GetTotal2(int? par)
    {
        return 179;
    }

The call - it works :-)
https://localhost:8804/api/deals/total2